# How to Adjust jqGrid height based on screen resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

The jqgrid table have a scrollbar

I want to set a height of jqgrid table based on screen resolution

Currently I have set the height in pixel.

We have an requirement that page should not display vertical scrollbar

We have to set the jqgrid table height such that the page does not display vertical scrollbar

Currently we have a screen resolution of 1280 * 1024 and the page does not display any vertical  scrollbar.

But if user change the screen resolution to 1280 * 768 then the html page display vertical  scrollbar

we want to change the jqgrid table height so that the jqgrid table display less rows with jqgrid table vertical scrollbar.

I have tried the option

height : 100% and 'auto' but in both case page is displaying vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

You should resize your jqgrid when the window resizes

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#your_grid_id').jqGrid('setGridHeight',$(window).innerHeight());
});
```

Comment: i tried the same but its coming with vertical scroll bar.when the grid height increases or decreases with the change in the screen resolution, the grid height should fit in that size(or height) with out showing any vertical scroll bar.

Comment: you're talking about window or grid's scroll bar?

Comment: @ skafandri : It's about window's vertical scroll bar.

Comment: you can fix this by trying:
$('#your_grid_id').jqGrid('setGridHeight',$(window).innerHeight()-x);
x must be between 50 and 100

Or if your grid is shown complete, just add CSS property: overflow-y:hidden to your body
CSS: body{overflow-y:hidden}

Comment: One more problem when I resize my window, the grid height also need to resize.The above code is not working based on this.It sets the grid height on  first time only, when I resize window browser,height remains constant.

Comment: Bounding an event to a window is permanent. Maybe you have another problem, can you show me an online version of your issue?

Comment: I am right now working on a project using jqGrid, this solution solved my problem.

Comment: I've uploaded my jqGrid image in the following url. http://www.2shared.com/photo/6l2Objaq/jqGrid.html

Comment: There we can see 10 rows are coming in the way as it was earlier but at the same time the grid height only expands. What I need is rows also should be expanded when we use it in high resolution. Converse should also true when we use in low resolution screen

Comment: Hmm, this is not easy to do!
TD's height is fixed by jqGrid, is not meant to be editable, if you really want this, you have to edit jqGrid code to do it.
Tip:
in ui.jqgrid.css you can check that heights have been fixed
`code`
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 2px;
    white-space: pre;
}`code`

Comment: yes there I had made changes as height:auto and white-space:normal !important. Then also its not working